# SAP UI5 - Card - How to trigger a onclick over the card control which should lead to opening of a list control

Tags: sapui5

I have an issue with the Card (sap.f), i have some content on the first half of the card and i want to press the card and able to withdraw a list which i am not able to attain via Navigation List.
Please suggest which list control should be able to perform this.

```
<f:Card id="card">
    <f:layoutData>
       <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData columns="4"/>
          </f:layoutData>
                <f:content>
                  ..........
                        <CustomListItem type="Active" 
                                   press="onShowHideMenuPress">
                                         ........ There are some items here
                              <List id="list" visible="false"
                                      class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin 
                                            sapUiNoContentPadding">
                               </List>
                       </CustomListItem>
            </f:content>
</f:Card>
```

Then in the controller the function()

```
 onShowHideMenuPress: function()
    {
            this.getView().byId("list").setVisible(true);  
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried using customlistitem and card control to do this. I have written a function in controller of this view when i am passing the list id and trying to set the setExpanded method. But it seems customListItem control does not implement this method so obviously it does not work. Then i used NavigationListItem control because it does implement these function but there are two problems while using it, first it still does not expand the list and also it leaves a panel on the side bar. Do you have any other idea to correct it.

Comment: As per my understanding, you have a card with some content and you need to expand the card content. Is there any button on which the card content should be expanded or anything else which I have not understood it? Kindly share screenshots for better understanding.

Comment: No there is no button , the click is on the card itself.

Comment: Kindly share screenshots of the layout.

Comment: You can use [attachBrowserEvent](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control/methods/attachBrowserEvent) to each cards with `click` event type

Comment: I tried creating the list view dynamically but that does not help; any other idea on this pls. The error now i got in the console is "EventProvider.attachEvent: fnFunction must be a function"